# Where did my backup folder go on my external drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I've been successfully using a [Seagate FreeAgent Go](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FWGJIY) to backup my files for some time now.

Last night I moved a folder to this drive and may have unplugged it before safely ejecting it from Windows. When I went to use the drive again, the folder I moved wasn't there anymore. And since I moved it, it's not on the original computer either.

Is there any way to recover this folder?

Comment: Did all the files disappear, or just that one?

Comment: @soandos just that one folder. all other previously saved folders and files are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a program like [Restoration](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/restoration.HTML) to try and recover the data.
Note: Do NOT run any kind of defrag on the drive until you get you data back. It would be bad, as programs like restoration look for data that was deleted, but not overwritten. Since defragmenting is all about rearranging files on the drive, it would overwrite a lot of data (potentially).

Comment: i actually used this and Recuva and got all my files back. i looked on the drive i moved it from. thanks!